# Como criar dom sem javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5, dom

Gostaria de saber se um navegador web, assim como o firefox, chrome etc usa o javascript para fazer dom no html! Então, é o javascript que faz o dom no html? Tipo assim, quando o navegador faz a renderização ele faz o dom certo? Esse dom é feito com o javascript?

Answer (score 1):

A explicação de [DOM (em Português) na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/DOM/Referencia_do_DOM) é boa. Tirando excertos de lá:

> O Modelo de Objeto de Documento  (DOM) é uma interface de programação para documentos HTML, XML e SVG.
>   [...]
>   Embora o DOM seja frequentemente acessado usando JavaScript, não é uma parte da linguagem JavaScript. Ele também pode ser acessado por outras linguagens.

Há um outro artigo interessante [na W3C (em Inglês)](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-DOM/introduction.html) onde diz:

> As a W3C specification, one important objective for the Document Object Model is to provide a standard programming interface that can be used in a wide variety of environments and applications.

ou seja, em termos de resumo "pode ser usado em variados ambientes e aplicações". E mais à frente referem *"In addition to the OMG IDL specification, we provide language bindings for Java and ECMAScript."*

Se tiveremos em conta que no browser é comum usar JavaScript para manipular o DOM, essa näo é a unica linguagem que pode manipular o DOM, no browser desktop ou mobile.